# Is it possible to modify labels in ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, validation

Is it possible to modify labels on the client side, such that the server side is able to see these modifications?

The reason I'm asking is because I'm applying input validation on server side code to mitigate against various attacks, and I'm wondering if I need to validate the label values. Could an attacker use Javascript to change them on the client side, and if so, would that be reflected on the server side?

Answer (score 0):

You only should be concerned about any user input into form fields or AJAX requests. You should **always** validate user input coming from the client on the server.

You can modify a label which is nothing more than a DOM element but it would not adjust the code on your server directly. Labels aren't automatically sent with a request.

Comment: Thanks. So, should I validate labels? Are they considered "user input", or can an attacker modify the labels so that it affects its server side value?

Comment: "should I validate labels? Are they considered "user input", or can an attacker modify the labels so that it affects its server side value?" **No**, **No**. You need to validate only what come in **Request** and used in server-side code.

Comment: Labels data is not sent to the server during a POST request. So, you won't get it on the server side. No data, no validation is required.